# Comparing lines algorithm advice

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, geometry, distance

Line is array of points (two or more). Each point has X and Y coordinate(double).
I have a plane full of lines.
I need some measure which will tell me how close and how similar are any two lines from plane. I need this measure to be 0 when lines are exactly the same, and its value must increase when line is roatating, shifting, or has completely different geometry.
For start if someone knows a name of good algorithm for this it would be good.

UPDATE:
Possible usage is this: I have a road with approximate geometry. I have a road network. I must find another road in road network which is probably the road I am searching for. But for some other reasons, i require this measure also. It is not enough to find the road, I must give a number which tells how much is my match good and how close are other matches.

Notice that two line do not have to be different if points are different.

Also if someone knows where can i find code or library for this algorithm in C# it would be great.

Comment: Please show your code and let us know what part you're having trouble with.  Stack Overflow is not a great place to ask people to write code for you.

Comment: Code it to big for here, also I do not require code, if someone can give me some algorithm or link with possible solution it would be great.

Comment: Omg is this just a cookbook site, I just asked for algortihm advice??? WTF?

Comment: -1 for ambiguity in problem statement.  A couple of examples:  Either say or show (with 2 lines of code) what you mean by "Line is array of points".  How many points per line?  If each line is defined by 2 points, does "line is part of another line" mean the lines partly overlap, or one is completely within another, or what?  What does "part of" mean if each line is point-to-point defined by multiple points?

Comment: Can someone explain downvotes here? I require two algorithms for some problems, why is this bad place?

Comment: @jwpat7 Thx, i will update question.

Comment: OK, I removed "ambiguities" and simplified question a bit. I relay dont't understand why only questions with code pass by.

Answer (score 1):

a word of warning: graphical pattern recognition isn't my favourite hobby, so this may be total bullshit ...

i would try to find some heuristics that can tell something about certain similarities between the compared lines ...

trivial checks first:

are the sets of points equal?

look at the point count:
if both lines have the same number of points:
measure the relative distances from point to point in both lines ...
measure the angular change when walking from point to point in both lines ...
... sum up the differences (and their absolutes) and you got some metrics

if both lines don't have the same number of points:

lay the lines over a grid, and mark the cells of that grid that are touched by the line ... count the diffs ... try different grid resolutions

go through the lines, track your walking direction and remove points that have a small angular difference to your walking direction... once you hit a point with a larger angular change, make that your new walking direction, and leave the point ... afterwards, try other metrics

to find rotation and scale:

try to calculate/find 3 accumulations of points, or characteristic points (points with similar angular change, preferably not close to each other and with a uncommon angular change) and try to rotate/stretch/mirror ... you will probably want to calculate all other metrics for each possible version, and take the best result if applicatable

if stuff like that does not give usable results to you ... looks like there is a lot of math waiting for you ...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform